# how use IEHtmlWindow widget change html form

Tags: python, wxpython

all

i want to use wx.lib.iewin develop a soft. the soft include an ie frame and three buttons. when i click one button , the ie frame can click an url like 'google.com', and click another button can set some value in google.com 's search input form. and last button can click google.com 's search button.

i know how to navigate google url.

```
    self.ie = iewin.IEHtmlWindow(self.panel_left,pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(465,560),style=wx.html.HW_SCROLLBAR_AUTO)
    self.ie.AddEventSink(self.panel_left)
    self.ie.Navigate('http://google.com')
```

but' how i can get the ie 's document . and change dom's value.

Answer (score 0):

The document object should be accessible as `self.ie.ctrl.Document`.

Comment: but i can't get any document with this object detail. pls give me some articles about it.

Comment: It is a COM wrapper around DispHTMLDocument (if it is an HTML document that is loaded, it may be an instance of another type in other cases.)  You can look up all the details about it at MSDN.