# why my qt webView can't return html

Tags: html, pyqt, activex, qwebview

all

a few days ago,i use wxpython want to access ie. but i don't know how to use activex ie with python. my question link [how use IEHtmlWindow widget change html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106096/how-use-iehtmlwindow-widget-change-html-form)

so i use pyQt to develop GUI program.

```
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.centralwidget)
    self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 571, 231))
    self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("about:blank")))
    self.webView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("webView"))
    self.webView.load(QUrl('http://zzxh.zjsgat.gov.cn:6081/zjwwzzxh/'))
    frame = self.webView.page().mainFrame()
    print unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')
```

i run front code. but it's also return following result

```
   <html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i know why it's always return ''  , besause  .toHtml() method must need the page load success.